# Capturar object id desde un trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, plsql, store

se puede capturar y guardar en el **object id (STORE PROCEDURE)** que hizo insert o update sobre una tabla especifica, con un trigger, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio y por favor lee [ask]. Lectura recomendada: acerca de [investigar previamente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/156327)

Comment: No, no se puede.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho muchas gracias!

Comment: Muy escueto mi comentario ahora que lo veo, debería haberte dicho, No, al menos de una forma segura. Revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468228/6836377, hay algunas recetas, pero ciertamente son complejas, no del todo confiables y penalizan la performance sin duda. Si tienes control sobre los Sps, es preferible que sean estos los que registren la actividad sobre las tablas.